# Question not visible from certain computers

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

This sounds strange: when I go to the webpage [The units of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280878/the-units-of-mathbb-z-sqrt2), in the right pane, under "Linked", there is a link to the webpage  [Determine all units of the domain $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438913/determine-all-units-of-the-domain-mathbbz-sqrt2) which is the question I posted.  Clicking on this link when I use my laptop takes me to the linked page correctly, but when I use my desktop PC or iPad, clicking on this link keeps me at this same page.  Why does this problem occur? Also, for my reference, I wonder if this linked page can be made visible from all PCs, including from my profile.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438913/determine-all-units-of-the-domain-mathbbz-sqrt2 is marked as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280878/the-units-of-mathbb-z-sqrt2. I think there is a forwarding mechanism that might be working in some cases and not others.

Comment: Were you logged in? This feature request at meta.SO is marked as [meta-tag:status-completed]: [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible explanation would be that in one of those two cases you were not logged in. Anonymous users are redirected to a duplicate.

See this meta.SO post [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr).

Comment: You are right,  I wasn't logged in during those two instances when I wasn't redirected.  That answers my question, thanks.